# how to insert in parent model if i add in chield model in django using django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

i have 3 Models as the follwing:
1- parent models "Batches" contain id & tabel name

```
class Batch(models.Model):
    table_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

2- Chield model 1 "Table 1"

```
class Table1(models.Model):
   text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   batch_num = models.ForeignKey(Batch, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

3- Chield model 1 "Table2"

```
class Table2(models.Model):
   text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   batch_num = models.ForeignKey(Batch, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

i need if add any transaction in table1 or table2 cereat transaction in parent model "Batch" and fill class name in parent table.
is there any good idea to make this throug django admin

- for more explanation i want to make one table include all transaction of my project and name of class that create this transaction
- any idea will help me

note:

i tried TabularInline but this is work when i add parent frist then allocate chield to parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can write Triggers for that.

```
from django.db import connection  #imports connection

cursor = connection.cursor() #creates cursor

raw_query = ''' Your Trigger code goes here '''
cursor.execute(raw_query) #execute the database query
```

I hope you find this helpfull.